# How to Extract IPv4 with following Bat File

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, extract, ping, ipv4

I am trying to find the correct way to extract the following IP Address from a network server, but I am unable to return just the ip address.

Theoretically if I had a 1111s1 as a server, I should be able to grab an Ip Address, but I am still not receiving an answer. Can someone please help me figure this part? I am still new to the Variable Concepts.

---

```
@echo off
:SETUP_PRINTER
cls
mode con: cols=65 lines=30
echo.
echo --------------------------
echo.     Printer Setup
echo --------------------------
set /p SPrnt=Name of Place:
echo.
FOR /F "tokens=2,3" %%A IN ('ping "%SPrnt%s1" -n 1 -4') DO IF "from"=="%%A" set "IP=%%~B"
echo. %IP%
echo. 
echo.  Printer IPs:
echo.
echo.  .30 - Test       .37 - Test
echo.  .31 - Test       .38 - Test
echo.  .32 - Test       .39 - Test
echo.  .33 - Test       .40 - Test
echo.  .34 - Test       .41 - Test
echo.  .35 - Test       .42 - Test
echo.  .36 - Test       .43 - Test
echo.  .23 - Test       .61 - Test
echo.  .24 - Test
echo.
pause
goto MAINMENU
```

---

[image: Attempted Failure When Tested]

Comment: [don't put images of code and text output here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). copy and paste them instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the address from DNS resolution instead of "reply from"

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -n 1 -4 "%SPrnt%s1"') do @echo %%a
```

If you `ping` a hostname, you get something like:

```
Ping wird ausgeführt für hostname [192.168.100.153] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
```

(the language may change, but the syntax `..... [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd] .....` is always the same)

The `for /f` loop gets the second token (because of the delimiters, the first token is anything before `[`, second token is anything inside `[` and `]`, third token is anything after `]`), so the second token is exactly the desired IP address.

See [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi Stephan,
Can you by chance explain the process on yours? I'm still not understanding like the concept of this. =)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `NSLookUp` instead of `Ping`:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2" %%A In ('NSLookUp 1111s1 2^>Nul'
) Do If Not Defined IP Set "IP=%%A"
```

Comment: gives me the IP of the server, not of my actual PC.

Comment: @Stephan, that's exactly what I read as the requirement. The IP Address attributed to the printer/server with the name 1111s1.

Comment: `nslookup` gives me `Server`, `Address`, `Name`, `Address`. Your method reports the first Address (Server), but we need the address for `Name` (given Hostname)